# Why am I getting the error "Cannot set properties of undefined" in NestJs?

Tags: express, nestjs

I'm trying to set the value of csrfToken in the session:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import * as session from 'express-session';

@Injectable()
export class CsrfMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    session({
      secret: 'my-secret',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    });
    req.session.csrfToken = uuidv4();
    // other logic
    next();
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error:
"TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'csrfToken')"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session` called in that manner does not modify the `req` object. *Normally* when calling a middleware, you do it like `app.use(session(options))` or `consumer.apply(options)` in the case of a `NestModule`'s `configure` method.

To do what you're trying to, you either need to call the middleware like

```js
@Injectable()
export class CsrfMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  async use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      session({
        secret: 'my-secret',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
      })(req, res, resolve);
    });
    req.session.csrfToken = uuidv4();
    // other logic
    next();
  }
}
```

Or you need to have the `session` call be a separate, earlier called middleware. Again, you can do this with `app.use()` in the `main.ts` or in a `configure` method of a `NestModule`

---

To do this with a `NestModule` you could do something like the following.

```js
@Module({})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {

  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(session(options), CsrfMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please advise on how to do this in the `configure` method of a `NestModule`?